# Install Windows XP In PC

Tags: windows-xp

I got stuck on one problem, I have PC which use to have Windows XP install, somehow someone format the C drive. I want to install Windows XP again.

I change the BIOS Setting to boot from CD drive, its display booting form ATAPI CD drive, Stating MS DOS, ask me date and time and after few moment the PC goes to C drive. There is nothing only one file in the C drive and I cannot open it.

Any suggestion and help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that CD is a proper stand-alone installation CD?

Comment: Do you have a bootable windows XP installation CD with you? If it cannot boot from CD drive, it will move to the next boot option - which could be your HDD.

Comment: Windows XP is no longer supported, and no longer gets even basic security updates. It's irresponsible and unsafe to continue using it.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is asking for date and time, it sounds like the CMOS battery is dead. Therefore it is probably not saving your BIOS changes to the boot order. Put a fresh battery in and try again.

[image]

Once the battery is replaced, you will have to enter the date & time again and set the boot order. Remember to save your changes when exiting BIOS.

After that, reboot and it should give you the option to boot from your Windows installation CD.

Comment: I change the battery, does not work. Every time I change the BIOS to CD, Floppy Disk and USB but when its loading its shows "Booting form ATAPI CD Drive" also its save the BIOS Setting.

Comment: Have you verified the CD is bootable on another computer? Or try a known working bootable CD.

Comment: Yes CD and Drive both working

Comment: When you say the drive is working, you mean anther CD will boot the computer, but your Windows CD does not?

Comment: I remove the CD drive and use on other PC, and bootable disk both are working on other PC

Comment: You could try flashing the BIOS. Maybe it was corrupted somehow. After that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What was the issue?